# Pass large amount of data through Posix queue

Tags: c, queue, pthreads, posix

I am trying to pass a large amount of data between threads in C (Raspberry with Debian).
I want to create 32 queues. I need to pass messages of 105 bytes each one. I want to pass 105 bytes each 4 ms to anothe thread for about 20 seconds (30 seconds top).

What I found with posix queues is that I cannot modify mq_msgsize parameter. I can modify mq_maxmsg but if I try to modify the other, queue does not work. It just work with 1024 bytes.

I think I have not understood mq_maxmsg and mq_msgsize parameters. I thought that mq_maxmsg is the number of messages I can store in the queue and mq_msgsize the size of each parameter.

In mq_send function I should pass the buffer I have with a value of 105 bytes. 
In mq_receive function I should read 105 bytes each time. 
Is this right?
If I try this, send/received does not work. Only with 1024.

This is how I am declaring the queues (I have 32 right now, but all of them are created equally):

```
#define Q_MOTOR_SIZE            1024

struct mq_attr          mq_motor_attr;
mq_motor_attr.mq_flags      = 0;
mq_motor_attr.mq_maxmsg     = 10000;
mq_motor_attr.mq_msgsize    = Q_MOTOR_SIZE;   #I tried to change this value by 105
mq_motor_attr.mq_curmsgs    = 0;
PR_mq_motor[0] = mq_open(MOTOR_0_Q_NAME, O_CREAT| O_RDONLY| O_NONBLOCK, 0644, &mq_motor_attr);
PR_mq_motor[1] = mq_open(MOTOR_1_Q_NAME, O_CREAT| O_RDONLY| O_NONBLOCK, 0644, &mq_motor_attr);
...
PR_mq_motor[31] = mq_open(MOTOR_31_Q_NAME, O_CREAT| O_RDONLY| O_NONBLOCK, 0644, &mq_motor_attr);
```

Every time I send a bunch of frames (105 bytes), should I send 1024 or it should work with 105 as packet size?

```
mq_send(PR_mq_motor[motor_counter], PR_queue_buffer, 1024, 0);
```

vs

```
mq_send(PR_mq_motor[motor_counter], PR_queue_buffer, 105, 0);
```

Same happens in the recevie part. If I try to read 105 instead of 1024, it crashes somewhere during the operation.

What should I do here? In case something needs to be modified on the raspi configuration, it is not a problem.

As @Shawn suggested. I implemented a linked list in order to have the 32 queues I wanted in the beggining.

I created some arrays to keep track of all the mutex to control access and the header of each list.

I think push is working fine but I have some kind of issue while popping elements.

As I said, I want to storage buffers of 8 bytes each one so I created the struct with buffers of 10 to be sure.

```
int16_t LL_M_Push(uint8_t LL_M_motor, uint8_t *LL_M_frame, uint16_t LL_M_size) {

pthread_mutex_lock(&PR_LL_M_lock[LL_M_motor]);

PR_LL_M_node_t *current = PR_LL_M_head[LL_M_motor];
if (current != NULL) {
    while (current->next != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
    }

    /* now we can add a new variable */
    current->next = malloc(sizeof(PR_LL_M_node_t));
    memcpy(current->next->val, LL_M_frame, LL_M_size);
    current->next->next = NULL;
} else {
    PR_LL_M_head[LL_M_motor] = malloc(sizeof(PR_LL_M_node_t));
    memcpy(PR_LL_M_head[LL_M_motor]->val, LL_M_frame, LL_M_size);
    PR_LL_M_head[LL_M_motor]->next = NULL;
}
PR_LL_M_counter[LL_M_motor]++;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&PR_LL_M_lock[LL_M_motor]);

return PR_LL_M_counter[LL_M_motor];
}

int16_t LL_M_Pop(uint8_t LL_M_motor, uint8_t *LL_M_element) {
uint8_t         *retval;
PR_LL_M_node_t  *next_node  = NULL;

pthread_mutex_lock(&PR_LL_M_lock[LL_M_motor]);
if ((PR_LL_M_head[LL_M_motor] == NULL) || (PR_LL_M_counter[LL_M_motor] == 0)) {
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&PR_LL_M_lock[LL_M_motor]);
    return -1;
}

next_node               = PR_LL_M_head[LL_M_motor]->next;
retval                  = PR_LL_M_head[LL_M_motor]->val;
memcpy(LL_M_element, retval, 10);
PR_LL_M_counter[LL_M_motor]--;
free(PR_LL_M_head[LL_M_motor]);
PR_LL_M_head[LL_M_motor] = next_node;

pthread_mutex_unlock(&PR_LL_M_lock[LL_M_motor]);

return PR_LL_M_counter[LL_M_motor];
}
```

Do you see something wrong here? Do you need something else?

Comment: There's no reason to use posix message queues if you're just passing data among different threads. They're meant for communication between different processes. Just use a normal mutex protected queue, or if you're feeling fancy, a lock free one.

Comment: Memory Mapping with MuteXs could be your solution.

Comment: @Shawn Could you please give me an example of a normal mutex protected queue? I searched on the Internet but I didn't found any implementation I could import.

Comment: Could sys/queue.h work with 2 threads? I just want to add in one and remove in another one. If I add a mutex to block the other thread while I am writing/reading...

Comment: A linked list is the simplest... Push to the tail, pop from the head, protect all operations with a mutex.

Comment: @Shawn, I created a LL as you suggested. It seems to works "more or less". Sometimes I get a memory fault while popping elements. I added the code just in case.